Two girls travelling, one gets robbed by a cowboy
I'm not sure if it's a '90s or probably an '80s film. I saw a bit of this film on tv. American production I believe. 
The scene I saw is about two girls travelling together by car what seems to be across Texas. They stop somewhere for the night and one of the girls meets a young cowboy. The girl and the guy have sex and spend the night together. However, the girl wakes up alone and realise the guy robbed her. She then joins her friend and carry on driving. Later on the girls meet the cowboy again.  The girl tells her friend he's the thief.
That's the only I have but I want to know what movie it was. Missed the begin and end of the film :(

Can we rule out Thelma & Louise right off the bat? (Also, do you remember who the actors were or what they looked like? Other plot details\scenes?)

Oh my gosh! That is the movie! "Thelma & Louise". I just looked it up. I realised how faded my memories of the film were. To be honest I didn't sit to watch it back then. It was being shown on tv while I was helping my brother fix the stove :) Thank you so much Walt, you're awesome!

I see. I figured Brad Pitt would be too memorable for this to be right, but I guess I was wrong. ;) Shall I put this up?

I guess no-one knew who he was at that time. I didn't, & it took me a while to realise that's where I first saw him.

@Walt, yes please. Thanks

You're looking for Ridley Scott's Thelma & Louise from 1991, a film that has since become iconic. During the 2 female protagonists' long and fateful road trip:

Heading west, they come across an attractive young man named J.D. (Brad Pitt), and Thelma convinces Louise to let him hitch a ride with them. [...] Thelma invites J.D. into her room and learns he is a thief who has broken parole. They sleep together, and J.D. describes how he conducted his hold-ups. [...] In the morning, Thelma tells Louise about her night with J.D. When they return to the motel room, they discover J.D. has taken Louise's life savings and fled.

Here's Pitt as J.D.  trying to hitch a ride:




Uhmmmm.....was this a serious question?  How can someone not know this?  Hat's off to you Walt.....no pun intended ;)
